# Revision history of question doesn't display revision author

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, specific-question, revision-history

I came upon [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60604311/revisions) during some small amount of research if there was anything else missing from the question, like a React tag.  From what I can tell, a non-OP person edited the question to include React or React-like code in the question, and left the edit summary on [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60604311/2).  However, their name was not recorded under the edit.

In case the question is deleted between now and later, here is the edit revision text:

> OP's question was closed because it was unclear. I understand what he meant though. Edited it.

This revision was by the OP in question, which is what lead to my confusion of the origin of the revision.

If this is indeed a bug and not a one-off edge case, here's the report.

Comment: I did attempt to find a relevant duplicate before posting this, but my search terms may be off, because I wasn't able to.

Comment: The OP [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25561362) the edit, deciding to edit by themselves.

Comment: @HansPassant ... Ahh.  Well, I'll be looking for a user script to find a link to that now.  Should I delete this question?

Comment: I think this question might as well stay up because that was a confusing looking edit.

Comment: No, that user forgot to update the revision message after they [rejected a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25561362) but used it as a starting point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a method I can use to find the review that links to the revision?

Comment: It's weird that the system let the OP use the suggested edit as a starting point while rejecting the edit. You can't do that in the review queue; if you choose Reject and Edit you start from the previous revision. Also, why does it say it was a conflict and not a Rejection?

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica: You can find suggested edits in the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60604311/timeline),

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did actually check the timeline several times, but I guess I didn't look closely enough because I see the suggestion now.  My bad for the waste of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making assumptions based on the content of the revision message here:

> OP's question was closed because it was unclear. I understand what he meant though. Edited it.

but the edit really *was* made by the OP. They are correctly named as the editor of that revision, there is no bug here.

What happened is that [a suggested edit was made](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25561362) which used that exact revision comment. The OP used that edit as the basis for their own edit but added a HTML code block.

They simply didn't realise they could set a revision comment or forgot to change it.